# Solve the coefficient of a cubic polynomial of vector

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

Consider the problem: Given $B, D, C^i\in \mathbb{R}^{N\times N}$ for $1\le i\le N$, I aim to find $A^i\in \mathbb{R}^{N\times  N}$, $1\le i\le N$ such that they satisfy the following cubic polynomial on $\mathbb{R}^{N}$:
$$
F(x)=(x^T\begin{pmatrix} A^1\\\vdots\\A^n \end{pmatrix}x,Bx)=(x^T\begin{pmatrix} C^1\\\vdots\\C^n \end{pmatrix}x,Dx), \quad \forall x\in \mathbb{R}^{n},\qquad\qquad{(1)}
$$
where I denote $$x^T\begin{pmatrix} A^1\\\vdots\\A^N \end{pmatrix}x =\begin{pmatrix} x^TA^1x\\\vdots\\x^TA^Nx \end{pmatrix}.$$

---

I try to express $A^i$ using $B,C^i$ and $D$. After taking third order mixed derivatives of (1), I obtain that 
$$
\frac{\partial^3 F}{\partial x_mx_nx_s}=A^i_{mn}B_{is}+A^i_{ms}B_{in}+A_{ns}^iB_{im}=C^i_{mn}D_{is}+C^i_{ms}D_{in}+C_{ns}^iD_{im}, \quad s,m,n=1,\cdots,N,
$$
which yields a $N^3$ linear system. Moreover, the coefficients of this linear system is hard to formulate, and the process destroys the original structure of $B,C,D$. Hence is there a more compact way such as
$$
\begin{pmatrix} A^1\\\vdots\\A^N \end{pmatrix}B=\begin{pmatrix} C^1\\\vdots\\C^N \end{pmatrix}D,
$$
to express the relation between $A,B,C,D$? Or is there an easier way to solve $A^i$?

Comment: I would suggest to look at the case $n = 1$ first. If you can solve that, you might be able to get an idea for the general case. If you already solved it, maybe post the solution. Another problem: You don't always have solutions. Take for example $B = 0$ and $D,C^i$ such that the right hand side produces non-zero values at some points... Do you have restrictions that always guarantee solutions (if yes: which ones and why?).

Comment: @Bemte Thanks for your comments. Indeed I have considered the one-dimensional problem, which implies $ab=cd$. Then $a$ can be solved if $b\not=0$. But the equality is the relation satisfied by the coefficients, no matter whether it has a solution. And for your second question, I haven't studied the existence of solutions yet.

Comment: Ah, I think you want $n = N$? I got a little confused by that...

Comment: The identity I get is by taking partial derivatives of the LHS: $\frac{\partial^3 F(x)}{\partial x_m x_nx_s}$, hence $m,n,s$ ranges from $1$ to $N$.

Comment: @Bemte Please kindly see the above comment.